# How to produce a snapshot table using Power BI measure

Tags: powerbi, dax

My intention is to populate days of the month to simulate a data warehouse periodic snapshot table using DAX measures. My goal is to show non-additive values for the quantity.

Consider the following transactions:

[image]

The granularity of my snapshot table is day. So it should show the following:

[image]

Take note that a day may have multiple entries but I am only interested in the latest entry for the day. If I am looking at the figures using a week period it should show the latest entry for the week. It all depends on the context fixter.

However after applying the measure I end up with:

[image]

There are three transactions. Two on day 2 and the other on day 4. Instead of calculating a running total I want to show the latest Qty for the days which have no transactions without running accumulating totals. So, day 4 should show 4 instead of summing up day 3 and day 4 which gives me 10. I've been experimenting with LASTNONBLANK without much success.

This is the measure I'm using:

```
Snapshot = 
CALCULATE(
    SUM('Inventory'[Quantity]),
    FILTER(
        ALL ( 'Date'[Date] ),
        'Date'[Date] <= MAX( 'Date'[Date] )
    )
)
```

There are two tables involved:

Table # 1: Inventory table containing the transactions. It includes the product id, the date/time the transaction was recorded and the quantity.

Table # 2: A date table 'Date' which has been marked as a date table in Power BI. There is a relationship between the Inventory and the Date table based on a date key. So, in the measure, 'Date'[Date] refers to the Date column in the Date table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the LASTNONBLANKVALUE function, that returns the last value of the expression specified as second parameter sorted by the column specified as first parameter.

Since LASTNONBLANKVALUE implicitly wraps the second parameter into a CALCULATE, a context transition happens and therefore the row context is transformed into the corresponding filter context. So we also need to use VALUES to apply the filter context to the T[Qty] column. The returned table is a single row column and DAX can automatically convert a single column, single row table to a scalar value.

Then, since we don't have a dimension table we have to get rid of cross-filtering, therefore we must use REMOVEFILTERS over the whole table.

the filter expression T[Day] < MaxDay is needed because LASTNONBLANKVALUE must be called in a filter context containing all the rows preceding and including the current one.

So, assuming that the table name is T with fields Day and Qty like in your sample data, this code should work

Edit: changed in order to support multiple rows with same day, assuming the desired result is the sum of the last day quantities

```
Measure =
VAR MaxDay =
    MAX ( T[Day] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
            T[Day],
            SUM ( T[Qty] )
        ),
        T[Day] <= MaxDay,
        REMOVEFILTERS ( T )
    ) + 0
```

Edit: after reading the comments, this might work on your model (untested)

```
Measure =
VAR MaxDay =
    MAX ( 'Date'[Date] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        LASTNONBLANKVALUE (
            Inventory[RecordedDate],
            SUM ( Inventory[Quantity] )
        ),
        'Date'[Date] <= MaxDay
    ) + 0
```

Comment: I tried your solution but it didn't work:
Error: MdxScript(Model) (11,13) Calculation error in measure T[Qty running total in Date]: A table of multiple values was supplied where a single value was expected.

Comment: It might be that the sample data you posted is not representative of your real data.The most probable difference might be that you may have different rows with the same Day. Assuming you want to sum Qty's for the same day, SUM (T[Qty]) can be used instead of VALUES(T[Qty])

Comment: What you're saying is correct, my situation allows multiple entries per day but only the last entry for the day (the most recent) should be used. For example:

Day   Time        Qty
------   --------      -----
2         08:00      5
2         10:00      3
3         14:00      2

So for the day 2 the only entry I'm interested i is the latest one at 10:00 with Qty 3.
In this case, what's the DAX function for the most recent entry for the day?

Comment: What is the most recent record between  (Day = 2, Qty = 3), (Day = 2, Qty = 4) ?
Do you have another field to be used to determine what's the most recent one?

Comment: Yes, I have a datetime column RecordedDate which gives me the date and time.

Comment: Just a question about your example. When you say T[Day] I assume you're referring to 'Date'[Day] and when you say T[Qty] you're referring to Inventory[Qty]? I have two tables which are Inventory and a Date tables.

Comment: Then you might want to be more precise and edit your question and add these details. In my example, as I wrote, I was assuming a single table with Day and Qty fields.

Comment: I have updated my question, hopefully it is a bit clearer.

Comment: Thank you. I changed my answer to include a new implementation that includes the RecordedDate column.